# python iterate into multiple variables

Tags: python, operating-system, file-listing

```
import os


directory="/home/user/Dropbox/"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith("jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".bmp"):
        a=(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        print(a)
```

How to assign result to multiple variables? For example:

```
pic1="/home/user/Dropbox/pic.jpg"
pic2="/home/user/Dropbox/pic3.jpg"
pic3=""/home/user/Dropbox/pic3.jpg"
```

Comment: Use a *container*, don't dynamically create variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use list to store variable values

```
import os


directory="/home/user/Dropbox/"
lst = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith("jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".bmp"):
        a=(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        lst.append(a)
print(lst)
```